# Suggestion of book covering well elementary matrix operations

Tags: matrices, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for some material that covers transformations as composition of elementary matrix, i don't know if it is clear as i'm stating, but if anyone have any suggestions i'm up to looking it up

Comment: The key phrase here is "linear algebra". See the [tag:linear-algebra] tag.

Comment: There are many popular books on linear algebra. You can find book suggestion threads on this site. Two books that come to mind are Introduction to Linear Algebra by Strang, and Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence.

Comment: strang doesn't cover what i want on elementary matrixes @littleO, i have found something on Carnahan book

Comment: @Shaun I'm actually requesting book recommendations, but sure i should have added they are in linear algebra topics